# Alignment of section titles in multi-column paragraphs in ConTeXt

Tags: context

I want to create two-column paragraphs. The alignment of left and right columns should be flush right and flush left, respectively.

The following example displays the main texts in the correct alignment, but the section titles always appear flush left:

```
\defineparagraphs[paras][n=2, distance=0.08\textwidth]
\setupparagraphs[paras][1][width=0.46\textwidth, align=flushright]
\setupparagraphs[paras][2][width=0.46\textwidth, align=flushleft]

\setuphead[section][style=bold, number=no]

\starttext
\startparas

\startsection[title=Knuth]
\input knuth
\stopsection

\nextparas

\startsection[title=Tufte]
\input tufte
\stopsection

\stopparas
\stoptext
```

and the result:
[image]

I want to set bold "Knuth" also flush right.
I know I can achieve the desired result by creating a custom section using `\definehead` like so:

```
\definehead[sectionr][section]
\setuphead[sectionr][align=flushright]
```

and use `\startsectionr ... \stopsectionr` within the right column.
However, I want to avoid using the custom header if possible.
Is there a way to achieve the same result without using a custom header?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `paragraph` mechanism is a simple table. If you are willing to use Natural Tables instead, then you can change the rendering of each column separately. For example:

```
\defineparagraphs[paras][n=2, distance=0.08\textwidth]
\setupparagraphs[paras][1][width=0.46\textwidth, align=flushright]
\setupparagraphs[paras][2][width=0.46\textwidth, align=flushleft]

\setuphead[section][style=bold, number=no]

\startsetups left
  \setuphead[section][align=flushright]
\stopsetups

\startsetups paragraphs
  \setupTABLE[frame=off]
  \setupTABLE[column][1,2][width=0.46\textwidth]
  \setupTABLE[column][1][roffset=0.04\textwidth, align=flushright, setups=left]
  \setupTABLE[column][2][loffset=0.04\textwidth, align=flushleft]
\stopsetups

\starttext
\startTABLE[setups=paragraphs]
  \NC 
      \startsection[title=Knuth]
        \input knuth
      \stopsection

  \NC

      \startsection[title=Tufte]
        \input tufte
      \stopsection

  \NC \NR
\stopTABLE
\stoptext
```